# Caret jumps to the right edge of the contenteditable element when deleting the last character next to the pill

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, caret

I have a pill and text inside a contenteditable element(div). However, after deleting the last character next to the pill, the caret jumps to the right edge of the contenteditable element. How to avoid the caret jumping(off-set)?

HTML:

```
<div class='container' contenteditable="true">
  <div class='pill' contenteditable="false" >Andy Green</div>Text B
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.pill {
  background-color: #b2ffb2;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3sn4emj0/10/

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by luck. Just add an empty  following the pill!

```
<div class='container' contenteditable="true">
 <div class='pill' contenteditable="false" >Andy Green</div><span></span>Text B
<span></span>
</div>
```

Please see the JsFiddle for details.
https://jsfiddle.net/3sn4emj0/12/

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. If you delete the text except the pill, then type some text (i.e. "hello") then delete THAT text except the pill you get the same problem.

The issue is that when you delete the text that is not the pill and then enter more text, that text gets put into the empty span you added. And then when you delete the new text you've entered the span gets removed and you're back to square one. So you need to always make sure there's an empty span beside the pill div.